# Crear objeto con formato de fecha determinado %d/%m/%y

Tags: python, django, django-models

Estoy intentando crear un objeto a partir de los rows de un csv. 
El problema que tengo es que no sé como almacenar la fecha del modelo como posee ya el csv "%d/%m/%y" sin que de

`["'27/10/16' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]`

Como lo tengo en el modelo

```
class Conver(models.Model):
   fecha = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Donde crea el objeto

```
def salvarEnBD(fileName):
with open("./apps/app1/modulos/csv/" + fileName.replace(".txt", ".csv")) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        _, created = Conversacion.objects.get_or_create(
            fecha = row[0],
            )
```

Comment: Bienvenido @JUANVERA a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Diría que el problema es qué, por supuesto, el formato de fecha que intentas pasar a la bbdd no es valido.

Una posible solución es utilizar la librería `dateutil`, con su módulo asociado `parser`.

```
import dateutil.parser

date_string = '27/10/16'
dt = dateutil.parser
new_date = dt.parse(date_string, dayfirst=True)
```

Si el tipo de dato que necesitas es de tipo `date` en vez de `dateutil`:

`new_date  = dt.parse(date_string, dayfirst=True).date()`

**Salida sobre la fecha de ejemplo del OP**

[image: Salida sobre el ejemplo del usuario]

Espero que te sirva de ayuda!!